# C# Adding colorful text from RichTextBox object to DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn(DataGridViewRichTextBoxCell)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a RichTextBox where the text is visualizing in the colors I set it to and I want to add it to a DataGridView the same way. I add the columns programmatically like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = "Зъб", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = "Дата", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { HeaderText = "Изпълнител", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell() });
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = "Описание", CellTemplate = new DataGridViewRichTextBoxCell() });
```

The last column is the one that should contain the RichTextBox text.
Before I add the text to the column i create a RichTextBox object which I use to convert the Rtf text code into text and after that i add it to the column, like this:

```
RichTextBox rtbox = new RichTextBox();
                                rtbox.Rtf = proc.Note;
                                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = rtbox.Text;
```

Where `proc.Note` is the Rtf code for the text.
But after compilation only the first 3 columns have data in them and nothing appears in the 4th.

Comment: What are you targeting? Winforms? Where does DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn come from??

Comment: @TaW I am guessing from here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView

Comment: That's what I guess as well, but it really is the OP's job to confirm this and to answer our questions in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yes it is about Winforms, but I decided to try and do this on the newest version of Visual Studio and I found that the DataGridView there does not support the Cell Type DataGridViewRichTextBox so I figured that what I want to do can't be done with the default DataGridView. But I am not sure how to make a custom one that will..